# Web application security concerns with user-uploaded files on Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, amazon-s3, paperclip

### Background

I have a web application where users may upload a wide variety of files (e.g. jpg, png, r, csv, epub, pdf, docx, nb, tex, etc). Currently, we whitelist exactly which files types are a user may upload. This limitation is sometimes annoying for users (i.e. because they must zip disallowed files, then upload the zip) and for us (i.e. because users write support asking for additional file types to be whitelisted).

### Ideal Solution

Ideally, I'd love to whitelist files more aggressively. Specifically, I'd would like to (1) figure out which file types may be trusted and (2) whitelist them all. Having a larger whitelist would be more convienient for users and it reduce the number of support tickets (if only very slightly).

### What I Know

I've done a few hours of research and have identified common problems (e.g. path traversal, placing assets in root directory, htaccess vulnerabilities, failure to validate mime type, etc). While this research has been interesting, my understanding is that many of these issues are moot (or considerably mitigated) if your assets are stored on Amazon S3 (or a similar cloud storage service) – which is how most modern web application manage user-uploaded files.

### Hasn't this question already been asked a zillion times?!

Please don't mistake this as a general "What are the security risks of user-uploaded content?" question. There are [already](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/upload-forms-threat) [many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864441/file-upload-security-concern) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354300/securing-file-upload) [like](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235/what-steps-should-be-taken-to-validate-user-uploaded-images-within-an-applicatio) [that](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/is-it-safe-to-store-and-replay-user-provided-mime-types) and I don't want to rehash that discussion here.

More specifically, my question is, "What risks, if any, exist given a conventional / modern web application setup?" In other words, I don't care about some old PHP app or vulnerabilities related to IE6. What should I be worried about assuming files are stored in a cloud service like AmazonS3?

### Context about infrastructure / architecture

So... To answer that, you'll probably need more context about my setup. That said, I suspect this is a relatively common setup and therefore hope the answers will be broadly useful to anyone writing a modern web application.

My stack

- Ruby on Rails application, hosted on Heroku
- Users may upload a variety of files (via Paperclip)
- Server validates both mime type and extension (against a whitelist)
- Files are stored on Amazon S3 (with varying ACL permissions)

When a user uploads a file...

- I upload the file directly on AS3 in a `tmp` folder (hasn't touched my server yet)
- My server then downloads the file from the `tmp` folder on AS3.
- Paperclip runs validations and executes any processing (e.g. cutting thumbnails of images)
- Finally, Paperclip places the file(s) back on AS3 in their new, permanent location.

When a user downloads a file...

- User clicks to download a file which sends a request to my API (e.g. `/api/atricle/123/download`)
- Internally, my API reads the file from AS3 and then serves it to the user (as content type attachment)
- Thus the file does briefly pass through my server (i.e. not merely a redirect)
- From the user's perspective, the file is served from my API (i.e. the user has no idea the file live on AS3)

### Questions

- Given this setup, is it safe to whitelist a wide range of file types?
- Are there some types of files that are always best avoided (e.g. JS files)?
- Are there any glaring flaws in my setup? I suspect not, but if so, please alert me!

Comment: Do you allow zip or rar files?

Comment: I came across this type of requirement in my project. So we run clamav anti virus scanner and filter the untrusted files. you can add this in your setup. In aws s3 we have done this using sqs and batch.

Comment: @MohanShanmugam Yes, we allow zip. This way users can always zip their files odd or unsupported file types before uploading. It's an okay solution but definitely inconvenient for users.

Comment: So you need to stop the unsupported file types. In python we read the zip file and get all files to validate, for the unsupported file extensions I throw error message in program.